# Como validar 2 grupos de checkbox

Tags: php, html

Pessoal no meu formulário tenho 2 grupos distintos que possui 4 checkbox cada. O 1º grupo já está validado.
Que é esse:
HTML com PHP, ele faz o loop com a quantidade de itens do banco:

```
<?php
$select_funcao = "SELECT * FROM funcao ORDER BY nome";
$result_funcao = mysqli_query($conexao, $select_funcao);
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result_funcao); $i++) {
        $linha_funcao = mysqli_fetch_array($result_funcao);
?>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="<?= $linha_funcao['codigo'] ?>">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="<?= $linha_funcao['codigo'] ?>" name="funcao[]" value="<?= $linha_funcao['codigo'] ?>"><?php echo $linha_funcao['nome'] ?>
            </label>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Com esse `Script`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validar() {    
    var i = 0, counter = 0, funcao;
    funcao = document.forms[0].elements['funcao[]'];
        for (; i < funcao.length; i++) {
            if (funcao[i].checked) {
                    counter++;
                }
        }

    if (counter == 0) {
        alert("Selecione pelo menos uma função para essa questão!");
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}
</script>
```

Esses 1º checkbox valida certinho, sem problemas.

A questão é que tenho outro grupo de checkbox:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="correto[]" value="1" class="checkgroup" aria-label="Chebox para permitir input text">
<input type="checkbox" name="correto[]" value="2" class="checkgroup" aria-label="Chebox para permitir input text">
<input type="checkbox" name="correto[]" value="3" class="checkgroup" aria-label="Chebox para permitir input text">
<input type="checkbox" name="correto[]" value="4" class="checkgroup" aria-label="Chebox para permitir input text">
```

Como fazer para validar esses acima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa usar tanto código para verificar se um checkbox foi marcado dentro de um grupo. Apenas com...

```
var funcao = document.querySelector("[name='funcao[]']:checked");
```

...você consegue saber se algum checkbox com `name='funcao[]'` foi marcado. Se nenhum tiver sido marcado irá retornar `null`, então você pode usar um `if(!funcao)` que verifica se `funcao` é `null`. Aí você faz a mesma coisa com o outro grupo `name='correto[]'`.

Veja como fica bem mais simples:

```js
function validar() {    

   var funcao = document.querySelector("[name='funcao[]']:checked");
   var correto = document.querySelector("[name='correto[]']:checked");

   if(!funcao){
      alert("Selecione pelo menos uma função para essa questão!");
      return false;
   }

   if(!correto){
      alert("Selecione pelo menos uma opção!");
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="c1">
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="c1" name="funcao[]" value="c1">função 1
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="c2">
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="c2" name="funcao[]" value="c2">função 2
      </label>
   </div>
   <br>
   Opções:
   <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="correto[]" value="1" class="checkgroup" aria-label="Chebox para permitir input text">
   <input type="checkbox" name="correto[]" value="2" class="checkgroup" aria-label="Chebox para permitir input text">
   <input type="checkbox" name="correto[]" value="3" class="checkgroup" aria-label="Chebox para permitir input text">
   <input type="checkbox" name="correto[]" value="4" class="checkgroup" aria-label="Chebox para permitir input text">
</form>
<button onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
```

Aprenda a usar o `document.querySelector` e o `document.querySelectorAll` que são muito úteis na hora de selecionar elementos, pois eles aceitam seletores CSS que torna a tarefa muito mais flexível e fácil.

Docs:

- [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Perfeito #Sam, vlw